# How to remove black pixel bleed? (Illustrator CC or Sketch)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, sketch-app, pixel, compression, bleed

I'm working with a color logo created in Illustrator. When it's exported as a PNG at a large size, it looks fine. If I export it at a smaller size, it creates a faint black line between the colors.

[image: black pixels added]
[image: shown at 1200%]

I've also opened it in Sketch to see if it was a program problem, but it's happening there too.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This is due to anti-aliasing. Red line in this instance has semi-transparent pixels running up the sides, when it overlays on the blue it creates a darker purple color.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't be concerned about this. You seem to be zoomed in quite far too. Also I'm pretty sure this is an artifact of raster anti-aliasing. If the "black line" or blend wasn't there, you would have a very jagged edge between colors.